# grunt-uncss removes dynamically added classes when it shouldn't

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, npm, uncss

I was introduced to Node.js today and built a very simple Hello, World app. I also started using grunt to automate builds and deployments.

I am using the Bootstrap framework and colors.css.

```
<div class="hello"><h1>Hello, World</h1></div>
```

I add a few color classes to some elements using jQuery.

```
console.log('dev mode');
$('.hello').addClass('bg-blue');
```

I run the code through grunt-uncss.

```
uncss: {
    dist: {
        files: {
            'dist/styles.min.css': 'index.html'
        }
    }
}
```

But none of the color classes including `bg-blue` are there in `styles.min.css`.

If I don't run the file through uncss, everything works as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also take a look at https://github.com/purifycss/purifycss

Answer (score 1):

Try using the timeout option. 
It allows you to wait for the JS to load and execute. 
See the option here - https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss/issues/1

```
uncss: {
    dist: {
       options : {
           timeout: 2000
       },
       files: {
            'dist/styles.min.css': 'index.html'
        }
    }
}
```

Also take a look at this discussion - https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss/issues/1

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. My script is wrapped in a global function, I hope that isn't a problem?

Comment: I don't think it should as long as it is being called properly. 
Did you try purifycss ?

Comment: Purifycss worked, but it is not removing *everything* that should be removed.

Comment: Well I guess you can raise an issue on their repo